# Does the magnitude of a nonzero determinant give any information about how close to singular the matrix is?

Tags: matrices, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra, singularity

As title says, I am wondering i the magnitude of a nonzero determinant give me information about the singularity of the matrix.

Can someone prove (or help me to understand how i could) prove this to be true or false?

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me, the magnitude of a nonzero determinant $\det A$ can not give any information about the singularity of the matrix $A$ because $A$ is not singular - can you please clarify? That being said, $\det \colon M_n(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous (with topology induced by any norm) so $\det^{-1}(0)$ is closed, hence the invertible matrices in $M_n(\mathbb R)$ form an open subset, so they can get arbitrarily close to singular matrices.

Comment: I mean about how close to singularity it is, if that makes more sense?

Comment: This depends on the meaning of "closeness". If you consider $M_n(\mathbb R)$ as $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ then you can, for example, look at the Euclidean distance between a non-singular and a singular matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not.  The determinant of a matrix is not invariant under scaling since for an $n$ by $n$ matrix,

$\det (\alpha A)=\alpha^{n} \det(A)$

Thus for example, if $n=1000$, and $\alpha=0.1$,

$\det(I)=1$

$\det(\alpha I)=1.0 \times 10^{-1000}$

A more appropriate measure of the singularity of a matrix is the condition number

$\kappa(A)=\| A \| \| A^{-1} \|$

Different norms can be used here, but when the euclidean norm is used, it can be shown that

$\kappa(A)=\sigma_{1}/\sigma_{n}$

where $\sigma_{1}$ and $\sigma_{n}$ are the largest and smallest singular values of $A$.

Comment: Why is $\kappa(A)$ an appropriate measure? $\begin{pmatrix}10^{-6}&0\\0&10^{-6}\end{pmatrix}$ has the same $\kappa$ value as $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ but is relatively more singular. $\|A^{-1}\|$ by itself is a better indicator.

Comment: Both of the matrices in your comment have the same behavior in terms of relative error in the solution to $Ax=b$.

Comment: Very sufficient argumentation, thank you :-)